# Wish for Instant Summons spell gives a sapphire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

Wish:

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. You don’t need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components.

Instant Summons:

> Components: V, S, M (a sapphire worth 1,000 gp)
>
> The spell leaves an invisible mark on its surface and invisibly inscribes the name of the item on the sapphire you use as the material component. Each time you cast this spell, you must use a different sapphire.

Wish bypasses material components, but Instant Summons relies on the material component within the spell itself. This brooks the following question:

Does the Wish spell create a 1000 gp sapphire when used to cast Instant Summons?

Comment: Given the power of a Wish spell, and the level you'd have to be to cast it, 1000GP profit is a minimal side-effect.

Comment: Didn't find that other question in my search for this, looks like this one is rightfully closed.

Comment: @Sawyer Yeah, my thought process was like "Wow, great question! Wait, seems familiar..." I always feel kind of bad about this type of closure, cos it's still a great question.

Comment: @Miniman duplicate questions have a huge purpose: they help people (like me) that search for some terms, and end up in the duplicate, then follow to the linked question. Dupes are breadcrumbs, "alias" to the other questions. Don't feel sorry about a dupe, there is no demerit in having one's own question marked as a dupe. EDIT: you can still upvote a dupe because it is a great question. But lets not bother the community with writing more answers than we need to. XD +1